# Running .exe generated via py2exe on Parallels Desktop

Tags: python, windows, macos, py2exe, parallels

I've generated an .exe file using py2exe on Windows XP. This executable runs smoothly on Windows XP and Windows 7 when distributed.

When launched on Windows XP emulated via Mac's Parallel Desktop, however, an error occurs stating that "the application failed to launch because the configuration is incorrect." and suggesting that I re-install it. If built with console enabled, no error message is generated by the system, and the console window flashes briefly before disappearing. The application does not launch.

When distributed, I launch the .exe from a directory also containing msvcp90.dll. I believe everything else is bundled into the .exe. I've included my setup.py file below for reference.

Has anyone managed to get an .exe generated via py2exe on a Windows system to subsequently run in Parallel Desktop?

setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os

sys.argv.append('py2exe')

setup(
    options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1}},
    windows = [{'script': "frontend.py"}],
    zipfile = None
)
```

Comment: I resolved this problem by compiling the application (same source and setup.py) on a Windows 7 machine instead of a Windows XP machine. I'm unsure why this solved the problem, but whatever dependency issues were present with the XP compilation vanish with the 7 compilation.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that this is due to the Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime DLLs not being installed on the Parallel Desktop XP. I think you probably need the Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributables installed; you can get them from here: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5582. 
Note that you might need the non-SP1 redistributables or the VC8/Visual C++ 2005 ones installed instead - I'm not sure exactly what is needed, and it may depend on Python version as well.

Generally this isn't a problem with Parallel Desktop, it's just a dependency which needs to be met and if you were using an installer, you would install the redistributables automatically. Once you have installed them once on the computer, it should just work.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It seemed like a promising solution. However, I tried installing both recommended sets of DLLs, and the problem persists. Additionally, I found an old distribution of the software which _will_ launch on the parallels system. That version was compiled on a Windows 7 machine with a setup and source file identical to the one above. Eerie. Really eerie.